# Runtime error due to WTTlog.DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, runtime-error

I'm running a VC++ code in VS2008 in Win8 OS.
When i click on "F5" (Run the project), I see that I get an errro message like below

> "The program can't start because, WTTLog.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem"

I manually copied the WTTLog.dll to the Release/Debug folder in the VS project I'm running. But I still get the error.

Can anyone kindly help me if I need to copy this WTTLog.DLL into some specific location ?
I tried registering this DLL,but getting the message like

> "The module WTTLog.Dll was loaded but entry point DllRegiterServer was
>   not found".

1) Can you kindly let me know how do I successfully execute my VC++ solution without getting WTTLog.DLL error ?

2) Also what is the reason we get this error ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy it to the directory above `Debug\Release` as, IIRC, that is the directory in which either `.exe` is executed.

Comment: @hmjd Windows also searches the directory containing the `.exe` for dll's, not just the current working directory.

Answer (score 3):

This file part of Microsoft Driver Test Manager/Studio.

the file location should be this..

```
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Driver Test Manager\Studio\wttlog.dll'
```

or

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Hardware Certification Kit\Tests\[architecture]\NTTEST\driverstest\storage\wdk
```

or

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Hardware Certification Kit\Controller
```

or

```
  C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\
```

Make sure while you are installing you are installing WTT(Testing Tool) Client..

IF not

Try (re)placing the dll there and you should be done with the problem,

Windows Driver Kit will be required or the Windows Testing Tool..

I hope this will do ... :)